# Show that the limit $p_n\to \sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Fixed point iteration is $p_n={p_{n-1}\over{2}}+{1\over p_{n-1}}$ $n=1,2,...$. As it is fixed point iteration $p_n=g(p_{n-1})$. Hence, $g(x)={x\over 2}+{1\over{x}}$.Can someone give me a head start and that could start this problem. I tried induction but got some really complicated expressions which I cannot simplify. I tried proving $\sqrt{2}<p_n<p_{n-1}$ by induction when $p_0$ is not $\sqrt{2}$. Maybe I am doing something wrong in my induction method.

Comment: if i recall correctly, the even terms of the sequence are monotonic, and the odd terms of the sequence are monotonic

Comment: Carry out the first few steps in some examples.  Try for example some cases with  $p_0 <0, 0 < p_0 < \sqrt{2}, p_0 = \sqrt{2}, p_0 > \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: If you look at the link I posted as a duplicate, you will have an idea of how many times this question was asked ;)

Comment: Thank you rtybase

Answer (score 0):

Hints: **if** the iteration converges the limit $l$ must verify $l  = g(l)$; is false the the sequence converges for all $p_0$ (if $p_0 = 0$...); but $g$ is contractive near...